# Join a single column of value labels to multiple columns of values in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables: `Preferences`, which shows students' meal preferences, and `Key`, which is a key to understanding what each of the values are for each meal item.

```
Preferences:

| Student_ID | Student_Name | Meat | Vegetable | Drink | Dessert |
|------------|--------------|------|-----------|-------|---------|
| 1          | Jeff         | 3    | 1         | 4     | 1       |
| 2          | Andrea       | 1    | 1         | 3     | 1       |
| 3          | Allison      | 3    | 2         | 7     | 1       |
| 4          | Randy        | 1    | 1         | 4     | 2       |
| 5          | Carl         | 2    | 5         | 2     | 2       |
| 6          | Bobby        | 1    | 6         | 7     | 2       |
| 7          | Julie        | 3    | 5         | 2     | 1       |
| 8          | Anna         | 1    | 6         | 7     | 2       |
| 9          | Carlos       | 1    | 6         | 2     | 2       |
| 10         | Roger        | 2    | 4         | 2     | 1       |
| 11         | Pierre       | 1    | 2         | 1     | 1       |
| 12         | Troy         | 2    | 3         | 3     | 1       |
| 13         | David        | 3    | 6         | 6     | 2       |
| 14         | Michaela     | 1    | 4         | 5     | 2       |
| 15         | Rose         | 1    | 4         | 6     | 1       |
| 16         | Anita        | 3    | 6         | 6     | 2       |
| 17         | Connor       | 3    | 3         | 3     | 1       |
| 18         | Eddie        | 1    | 2         | 7     | 1       |
| 19         | Karen        | 3    | 5         | 5     | 2       |
| 20         | Rachel       | 3    | 2         | 2     | 1       |
|            |              |      |           |       |         |

Key:

| Item_Type | Item     | Value |
|-----------|----------|-------|
| Meat      | Chicken  | 1     |
| Meat      | Beef     | 2     |
| Meat      | Fish     | 3     |
| Vegetable | Carrots  | 1     |
| Vegetable | Peas     | 2     |
| Vegetable | Corn     | 3     |
| Vegetable | Broccoli | 4     |
| Vegetable | Zucchini | 5     |
| Vegetable | Eggplant | 6     |
| Drink     | Water    | 1     |
| Drink     | Milk     | 2     |
| Drink     | Juice    | 3     |
| Drink     | Cola     | 4     |
| Drink     | Lemonade | 5     |
| Drink     | Tea      | 6     |
| Drink     | Punch    | 7     |
| Dessert   | Cake     | 1     |
| Dessert   | Pie      | 2     |
```

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to assign value labels to each column of meal item values in `Preferences` from the single `Item` column from `Key`. In other words, I want to `JOIN` the two tables **to create the following table**:

```
| Student_ID | Student_Name | Meat    | Vegetable | Drink    | Dessert |
|------------|--------------|---------|-----------|----------|---------|
| 1          | Jeff         | Fish    | Carrots   | Cola     | Cake    |
| 2          | Andrea       | Chicken | Carrots   | Juice    | Cake    |
| 3          | Allison      | Fish    | Peas      | Punch    | Cake    |
| 4          | Randy        | Chicken | Carrots   | Cola     | Pie     |
| 5          | Carl         | Beef    | Zucchini  | Milk     | Pie     |
| 6          | Bobby        | Chicken | Eggplant  | Punch    | Pie     |
| 7          | Julie        | Fish    | Zucchini  | Milk     | Cake    |
| 8          | Anna         | Chicken | Eggplant  | Punch    | Pie     |
| 9          | Carlos       | Chicken | Eggplant  | Milk     | Pie     |
| 10         | Roger        | Beef    | Broccoli  | Milk     | Cake    |
| 11         | Pierre       | Chicken | Peas      | Water    | Cake    |
| 12         | Troy         | Beef    | Corn      | Juice    | Cake    |
| 13         | David        | Fish    | Eggplant  | Tea      | Pie     |
| 14         | Michaela     | Chicken | Broccoli  | Lemonade | Pie     |
| 15         | Rose         | Chicken | Broccoli  | Tea      | Cake    |
| 16         | Anita        | Fish    | Eggplant  | Tea      | Pie     |
| 17         | Connor       | Fish    | Corn      | Juice    | Cake    |
| 18         | Eddie        | Chicken | Peas      | Punch    | Cake    |
| 19         | Karen        | Fish    | Zucchini  | Lemonade | Pie     |
| 20         | Rachel       | Fish    | Peas      | Milk     | Cake    |
|            |              |         |           |          |         |
```

Where each meal item value for each student in `Preferences` is matched to its appropriate label from the single `Item` column in `Key`.

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `the most efficient way` as you mentioned, but you can perform an `inner join` four times as the following:

```
Select P.Student_ID, P.Student_Name, 
K1.item as Meat, K2.item as Vegetable,K3.item as Drink, K4.item as Dessert
from Preferences P 
inner Join Key_ K1 On (P.Meat=K1.Value_ and K1.Item_Type='Meat')
inner Join Key_ K2 On (P.Vegetable=K2.Value_ and K2.Item_Type='Vegetable')
inner Join Key_ K3 On (P.Drink=K3.Value_ and K3.Item_Type='Drink')
inner Join Key_ K4 On (P.Dessert=K4.Value_ and K4.Item_Type='Dessert')
order by P.Student_ID
```

See demo from [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7iST7Rrpn91Tz8nDGJH7Z/0).

Comment: This was the easiest method for me to understand, as in the future I will be joining 3 tables with the labeling issue. I just extended the logic in this solution to joining more than 2 tables. I did a full join instead of an inner join though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with a single join.
It was implemented in MySQL, but with very slight changes it can be implemented in any other DB.

```
select    Preferences.Student_ID
         ,Preferences.Student_Name
         ,max(case `Key`.Item_Type when 'Meat'      then `Key`.item end) as Meat
         ,max(case `Key`.Item_Type when 'Vegetable' then `Key`.item end) as Vegetable
         ,max(case `Key`.Item_Type when 'Drink'     then `Key`.item end) as Drink
         ,max(case `Key`.Item_Type when 'Dessert'   then `Key`.item end) as Dessert
from Preferences join `Key`on 
         `Key`.Item_Type = 'Meat'      and `Key`.value = Preferences.Meat      
      or `Key`.Item_Type = 'Vegetable' and `Key`.value = Preferences.Vegetable 
      or `Key`.Item_Type = 'Drink'     and `Key`.value = Preferences.drink     
      or `Key`.Item_Type = 'Dessert'   and `Key`.value = Preferences.Dessert
group by Preferences.Student_ID, Preferences.Student_Name
order by Preferences.Student_ID
```

| Student_ID | Student_Name | Meat | Vegetable | Drink | Dessert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff | Fish | Carrots | Cola | Cake |
| 2 | Andrea | Chicken | Carrots | Juice | Cake |
| 3 | Allison | Fish | Peas | Punch | Cake |
| 4 | Randy | Chicken | Carrots | Cola | Pie |
| 5 | Carl | Beef | Zucchini | Milk | Pie |
| 6 | Bobby | Chicken | Eggplant | Punch | Pie |
| 7 | Julie | Fish | Zucchini | Milk | Cake |
| 8 | Anna | Chicken | Eggplant | Punch | Pie |
| 9 | Carlos | Chicken | Eggplant | Milk | Pie |
| 10 | Roger | Beef | Broccoli | Milk | Cake |
| 11 | Pierre | Chicken | Peas | Water | Cake |
| 12 | Troy | Beef | Corn | Juice | Cake |
| 13 | David | Fish | Eggplant | Tea | Pie |
| 14 | Michaela | Chicken | Broccoli | Lemonade | Pie |
| 15 | Rose | Chicken | Broccoli | Tea | Cake |
| 16 | Anita | Fish | Eggplant | Tea | Pie |
| 17 | Connor | Fish | Corn | Juice | Cake |
| 18 | Eddie | Chicken | Peas | Punch | Cake |
| 19 | Karen | Fish | Zucchini | Lemonade | Pie |
| 20 | Rachel | Fish | Peas | Milk | Cake |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=947f2f2b95833665948814f690a3e569&hide=3)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full, very lean SQL Server solution based on [unpivot & pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).
Please note that subquery is needed only for the pivot statement since any column that isn't part of that statement becomes part of an implicit group by.

```
select  *
from   (select  item
               ,food_type
               ,Student_ID
               ,Student_Name
        from    Preferences as p
        unpivot (food for food_type in (Meat,Vegetable,Drink,Dessert)) as u 
        join food on food.value =  u.food and  food.Item_Type = u.food_type) as pu
        pivot (max(item) for food_type in(Meat, Vegetable, Drink, Dessert)) as p
order by Student_ID
```

| Student_ID | Student_Name | Meat | Vegetable | Drink | Dessert |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff | Fish | Carrots | Cola | Cake |
| 2 | Andrea | Chicken | Carrots | Juice | Cake |
| 3 | Allison | Fish | Peas | Punch | Cake |
| 4 | Randy | Chicken | Carrots | Cola | Pie |
| 5 | Carl | Beef | Zucchini | Milk | Pie |
| 6 | Bobby | Chicken | Eggplant | Punch | Pie |
| 7 | Julie | Fish | Zucchini | Milk | Cake |
| 8 | Anna | Chicken | Eggplant | Punch | Pie |
| 9 | Carlos | Chicken | Eggplant | Milk | Pie |
| 10 | Roger | Beef | Broccoli | Milk | Cake |
| 11 | Pierre | Chicken | Peas | Water | Cake |
| 12 | Troy | Beef | Corn | Juice | Cake |
| 13 | David | Fish | Eggplant | Tea | Pie |
| 14 | Michaela | Chicken | Broccoli | Lemonade | Pie |
| 15 | Rose | Chicken | Broccoli | Tea | Cake |
| 16 | Anita | Fish | Eggplant | Tea | Pie |
| 17 | Connor | Fish | Corn | Juice | Cake |
| 18 | Eddie | Chicken | Peas | Punch | Cake |
| 19 | Karen | Fish | Zucchini | Lemonade | Pie |
| 20 | Rachel | Fish | Peas | Milk | Cake |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6899f39f9236e91b1192d7dd910ab490)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do two operations, first a [unpivot](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=unpivot&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bvalue_column%5D%5BargType%5D=string&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bvalue_column%5D%5Bvalue%5D=VALUE&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bname_column%5D%5BargType%5D=string&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bname_column%5D%5Bvalue%5D=ITEM_TYPE&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5BargType%5D=column_list&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Meat&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B1%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Veg&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B1%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B2%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Drink&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B2%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B3%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Dessert&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B3%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bcolumn_list%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B3%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5BtransformName%5D=unpivot&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5Bname%5D=Preferences&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B0%5D=2d982452-3a13-4397-a5d4-3e4d30827684&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B1%5D=8d8bd599-3be8-4bdd-a362-3afadf52a484&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B2%5D=40bf2ca1-112b-45a3-9b9b-a6426b9755c3&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B3%5D=b07644ab-0d08-4d9f-be80-b9186c2241ea&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B4%5D=24a9a27e-6140-4e9b-a185-e5c450a1e2b0&tableIdMap%5Bb5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B5%5D=1a910075-29bc-4966-ac26-accc816e6d10&columnIdMap%5B2d982452-3a13-4397-a5d4-3e4d30827684%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Student_ID&columnIdMap%5B2d982452-3a13-4397-a5d4-3e4d30827684%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5B8d8bd599-3be8-4bdd-a362-3afadf52a484%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Student_Name&columnIdMap%5B8d8bd599-3be8-4bdd-a362-3afadf52a484%5D%5BdataType%5D=string&columnIdMap%5B40bf2ca1-112b-45a3-9b9b-a6426b9755c3%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Meat&columnIdMap%5B40bf2ca1-112b-45a3-9b9b-a6426b9755c3%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5Bb07644ab-0d08-4d9f-be80-b9186c2241ea%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Veg&columnIdMap%5Bb07644ab-0d08-4d9f-be80-b9186c2241ea%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5B24a9a27e-6140-4e9b-a185-e5c450a1e2b0%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Drink&columnIdMap%5B24a9a27e-6140-4e9b-a185-e5c450a1e2b0%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5B1a910075-29bc-4966-ac26-accc816e6d10%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=Dessert&columnIdMap%5B1a910075-29bc-4966-ac26-accc816e6d10%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&baseTableId=b5d6d81c-88ac-4056-8d85-bd6a23b5423f&sqlString=SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20Preferences%0AUNPIVOT%28%20VALUE%20for%20ITEM_TYPE%20in%20%28%20Meat%2C%20Veg%2C%20Drink%2C%20Dessert%20%29%29) - and then an inner join. Not sure if you'd want to pivot the result again, but if you did I guess that would be a third operation.

```
WITH CTE_UNPIVOT AS (
SELECT * FROM Preferences
UNPIVOT( VALUE for ITEM_TYPE in ( Meat, Veg, Drink, Dessert ))
),
CTE_MAPPED AS (
SELECT * FROM CTE_UNPIVOT
INNER JOIN Key
ON CTE_UNPIVOT.ITEM_TYPE = Key.ITEM_TYPE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_MAPPED;
```